# C# ReSharper: Access to modified closure

Tags: c#, closures, resharper

I know there are a hundred questions on SO regarding the *Access to modified closure* warning, however the usual fix of creating a local copy of the referenced variable doesn't seem to be clearing the warning in my case.

Here's my code:

```
SessionServiceModel sessionCache = null;
foreach (var id in bookingIds)
{
    var booking = // Get booking from service given id

    if (booking == null)
        continue;

    if (sessionCache == null || sessionCache.Id != booking.SessionId)
    {
        // Usually this would clear the warning
        var sessionId = booking.SessionId;

        // "Access to modified closure" on proceeding sessionId reference
        sessionCache = _serviceProxy.Call<ISessionService>(svc => svc.Get(sessionId));
    }
    ...    
}
```

Using ReSharper 2017.1.1, implementing the suggested fix puts me into an infinite loop of creating more local variables for the closure, each referencing the last one:

```
var sessionId = booking.SessionId;
var id1 = sessionId; // ReSharper fix: Copy to local variable
long[] id2 = {id1}; // ReSharper fix: Wrap local variable in array
sessionCache = _serviceProxy.Call<ISessionService>(svc => svc.Get(id2[0]));
```

Obviously, there is something wrong in how I'm structuring this. Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Comment: I'd say you should thoughtfully consider R# suggestions, but not be a slave to them.

Comment: You may not worry about modified closure at all here, because your lambda (`svc => svc.Get(..)`) will be executed immediately inside `Call`.

Comment: For reasons @Evk mentioned, you could also reference the `JetBrains.Annotations` nuget package, and put the `InstantHandleAttribute` on the delegate in `Call`.

Comment: I've got a similar problem with R# 2017.3.5. I'm thinking it's a bug in ReSharper - wishing my employer would allow me to have a R# upgrade.